# Where can I find a Monk miniature?

Tags: miniatures, monk

I need a good monk mini, no weapons, ideally female elf. Where can I find one?

Material (lead vs plastic) and painted vs. unpainted is useful to know but are all doable.

Comment: Are you looking for a regular lead miniature, or prepainted plastic?

Comment: A gaming store?  Is this a trick question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: http://www.reapermini.com/OnlineStore/human/sku-down/02731

Yuri, Female Monk, from Reaper

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I like this one, although I painted him in more muted colors:

[image: order_of_the_fist]
<sub>(source: [privateerpress.com](https://privateerpress.com/files/products/32060_AllegiantoftheOrderoftheFist_WEB.jpg))</sub>